# Can Hive Joins be implemented in Apache Nifi?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hiveql, apache-nifi

I need to implement Hive Joins from Apache Nifi.

I found `PutHiveQL`, `PutHiveStreaming` and `SelectHiveQL` processors in Apache nifi, but was not able to find any use case regarding the Hive Joins implementation.

Comment: are you asking about https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins

Comment: Yes @daggett , Can they be used via Nifi?

Comment: just put your query in `SelectHiveQL` `HiveQL Select Query` parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to join queries in Hive, you can just use those processors as usual with your join query statements.

However, if you are looking to use different regular queries and then join them inside NiFi, I would find it rather difficult(but possible with [MergeRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.MergeRecord/) or [MergeContent](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.MergeContent/index.html)) because NiFi is not exactly built for joining queries.